# Priority Queue is not adding the correct data to the queue

Tags: java, data-structures, dijkstra

I am trying to solve a problem using a priority queue, where I have a two dimensional array `times` where indexes in the second dimension representing

0. starting edge,
1. ending edge, and
2. the distance between two edges

Also given is the edge at which to start, as integer `k`.

I tried solving using Dijkstra's graph algorithm.

Since in the below code the starting node is 2, **I am adding values [3,7] and [1,2] to the priority queue, but when polling the values I am getting [1,7] and [3,7].** It's working correctly for some other inputs, however.

Input:

```
 int times[][] = {{1,2,1},{2,3,7},{1,3,4},{2,1,2}};
 int n = 3, k = 2;
```

Code:

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.PriorityQueue;
    
    class PairData {
        int node;
        int wei;
    
        public PairData(int node, int wei) {
            this.node = node;
            this.wei = wei;
        }
    }
    public class NetworkDelayTime {
    
        public int networkDelayTime(int[][] times, int n, int k) {
    
            ArrayList<ArrayList<PairData>> adj= new ArrayList<>();
    
            for(int i=0;i<n+1;i++){
                adj.add(new ArrayList<PairData>());
            }
    
            for (int i=0;i<times.length;i++){
    
               adj.get(times[i][0]).add(new PairData(times[i][1],times[i][2]));
    
            }
    
            PriorityQueue<PairData>  pq= new PriorityQueue<>((a,b)-> {
                System.out.println(a.node+" "+a.wei);
                System.out.println(b.node+" "+b.wei);
               return a.wei=b.wei;
            });
    
            pq.add(new PairData(k,0));
    
            int[] ans = new int[n+1];
            Arrays.fill(ans,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            ans[k]=0;
    
    
            while (!pq.isEmpty()){
                PairData data=pq.poll();
                int v=data.node;
                int dis=data.wei;
                System.out.println("the poll data "+v);
                System.out.println("the poll data weight "+dis);
    
               for(PairData pa:adj.get(v)){
                   int curDis=pa.wei+dis;
                   if(curDis<ans[pa.node]){
                       ans[pa.node]=curDis;
                       System.out.println("The current node adding to "+curDis);
                       PairData pairData=new PairData(pa.node,curDis);
                       pq.add(pairData);
                   }
    
               }
    
            }
    
           int min=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ans));
            for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
                if(ans[i]==Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                    return -1;
                min=Math.max(ans[i],min);
            }
    
    
    
            return min;
    
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
                int times[][] = {{1,2,1},{2,3,7},{1,3,4},{2,1,2}};
                int n = 3, k = 2;
    
                NetworkDelayTime delayTime = new NetworkDelayTime();
    
                System.out.println(delayTime.networkDelayTime(times, n, k));
    
        }
    }
```

What's wrong my code, such that I do not receive back the same values from the queue that I enqueued?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John is correct it seems like you need to be doing a return either Integer.compare(a.wei, b.wei) or returning a.wei < b.wei. This is because the way you have it currently set up makes it assign a.wei to b.wei in the anonymous comparator in the priority queue. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

There may well be other problems with your code, but the issue you are asking about is surely caused by the comparator you have assigned to your `PriorityQueue`.  Consider:

> ```
>             PriorityQueue<PairData> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((a,b)-> {
>                 System.out.println(a.node+" "+a.wei);
>                 System.out.println(b.node+" "+b.wei);
>                return a.wei=b.wei;
>             });
> ```

In that comparator, `a.wei=b.wei` is an *assignment*.  You are modifying the `wei` field of one object being compared to be equal to the `wei` field of the other.  The `PairData` objects you pull out of that queue will be the same ones you put in, but you are modifying them while they are inside.

And this is not merely a matter of getting mixed up between `=` (assignment) and `==` (equality comparison).  Not only does the result of an `==` comparison have the wrong type, but an equality comparison is semantically the wrong computation to perform.  A [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) determines the relative order of pairs of objects, not just whether they are equal to each other.  In particular, its `compare()` method must

> Return[] a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Since your weights are modeled as `int`s, the `Integer` class provides a convenient way to write that:

```
            PriorityQueue<PairData>  pq= new PriorityQueue<>((a,b)-> {
                System.out.println(a.node+" "+a.wei);
                System.out.println(b.node+" "+b.wei);
                return Integer.compare(a.wei, b.wei);
            });
```